# Why are controller names are called resource?

Tags: php, controller, resources, phalcon

Im reading a Phalcon tutorial and controller names are called resources i.e. companies and invoices are controllers. And what do they mean when they call something a resource? I.e. what is a resource? Wikipedia or Google werent helpful.

> Controller names are resources and their actions are accesses for the
>   resources:

```
 <?php
 //Private area resources (backend)
 $privateResources = array(
 ’companies’ => array(’index’, ’search’, ’new’, ’edit’, ’save’,   
 ’create’,  ’delete’),
 ’invoices’ => array(’index’, ’profile’)
 );
 foreach ($privateResources as $resource => $actions) {
 $acl->addResource(new Phalcon\Acl\Resource($resource), $actions);
```

Comment: Here is a link to [Companies controller](https://github.com/phalcon/invo/blob/master/app/controllers/CompaniesController.php)

Comment: And please provide a reason why you're downvoting

Comment: Asking what are resources is no different than asking what is dependecy injection. If the latter was legit to ask here then this one too is legit.

Comment: I don't think they are called resources just because in foreach they are referred to as $resource, I remember vaguely from a class in college a teacher talking about resources in terms of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what do resources mean in PHP, it's not an arbitrary name.

> As resource variables hold special handlers to opened files, database
>   connections, image canvas areas and the like, converting to a resource
>   makes no sense.

And this what I remember the teacher was talking about.

[PHP: Resources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to ACL creation. To Phalcon all items in an ACL list are defined as roles (user permissions) and resources (whatever they might see)

Comment: So, 'resources' is just an arbitrary name and doesn't reflect the nature of a controller from the programming point of view?